# How to see if a mod is compatible with other mod(Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

Please tell me all the files I need to open,find and/or edit in order to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility information is up to the developer, so if you want specific information pertaining to whether the mod will work with another, it's best to ask the developers themselves, through a forum post or private messaging.

If it's information about mod version compatibility, the general rule is that mods for different versions of Minecraft, e.g. a mod for 1.6 and another mod for 1.8, will not be compatible. Again, it's best to check with the developer, as this can be untrue for some mods. 
Also, you should make sure you're not using one Minecraft version with mods for a different version, but I assume this is common sense.

Good luck!